# Is it conjectured that there are no odd multi-perfect numbers?

Tags: number-theory, perfect-numbers

It is conjectured that there is no odd perfect number.

But is there a stronger conjecture that there are no odd
multi-perfect numbers ? Wikipedia shows a useful link, but my
conjecture is not mentioned. Here is the link :

http://wwwhomes.uni-bielefeld.de/achim/mpn.html

The site claims that there are infinite many even perfect numbers,
although the mersenne-prime-conjecture is still open.

- Does anyone know if there are proofs that all multi-perfect numbers
  with abundancy $3$ to $6$ have been discovered ?
- Is it conjectured that no odd multi-perfect numbers exist ?

Comment: It might make sense to include the definition.

Comment: A number $n$ is called multi-perfect, if $\sigma(n)$, the sum of the divisors of $n$, is a multiple of $n$. In particular, $n$ is called perfect, if $\sigma(n)=2n$.

Comment: It seems the site should *not* have reported it as known that there are an infinite number of even perfect numbers. These are equivalent to knowing Mersene primes, and the count for the latter is not known to be infinite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding your question in the title, there is already an answer to a related MO question [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/150215).

I hereby reproduce the answer from the referenced MO question here:

> The earliest reference seems to be from 1966: E.A. Bugulov, *On the question of the existence of odd multiperfect numbers*, Kabardino-Balkarskaya State University Učen. Zap. **30** (1966) 9-19. [I could not find this article online.]
>
> Bugulov showed that an odd multiperfect number must have at least 11 distinct prime divisors, more precisely, odd $k$-perfect numbers contain at least $\omega$ distinct prime factors, where $(k,\omega) =$ (3, 11), (4,21), (5, 54),... This result is discussed and improved by Shigeru Nakamura, *On k-perfect numbers*, Journal of the Tokyo University of Mercantile Marine (Natural Sciences), **33** (1982) 43–50. [Listed [here](http://ci.nii.ac.jp/naid/110000273334/en), but not available online.]